# Isomorphic subbundles of codimension $1$ imply isomorphic quotients?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, quotient-spaces

This is a follow-up of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521077/why-isomorphic-subbundles-of-codimension-1-imply-isomorphic-bundles-and-quotie).

Let $\tilde V, \tilde W$ be two **isomorphic** real vector bundles of rank $k$ over a smooth manifold $M$.

Suppose there exist isomorphic subbundles $V \subseteq \tilde V,W \subseteq \tilde W$ of rank $k-1$, i.e $V \cong W$.

**Question:**  Is it true that $\tilde V/V \cong \tilde W/W$? (are the quotients isomoprhic?)

If $\tilde V,\tilde W$ are orientable, then the answer is positive, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521077/why-isomorphic-subbundles-of-codimension-1-imply-isomorphic-bundles-and-quotie). I wonder what happens if we don't assume they are orientable.

Comment: Let $V = W$, let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be two nonisomorphic line bundles, and let $\tilde{V} = V \oplus L_1, \tilde{W} = W \oplus L_2$. Are you sure this is the question you meant to ask?

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right. (I was too naive). Perhaps a better question would be to assume $\tilde V,\tilde W$ have  isomorphic orientation bundles. (The only way that comes to my mind to use your suggestion explicitly is to take the base $M=\mathbb{S}^1$, $L_1=\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}$, $L_2$ to be the Mobius bundle. Take $V=\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}$. In that case $\tilde V=V \oplus L_1$ is orientable and $\tilde W=V \oplus L_2$ is not. What happens if we don't allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you assume $\tilde{V}$ and $\tilde{W}$ are isomorphic then the quotients are isomorphic. This follows from a computation with [Stiefel-Whitney classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%E2%80%93Whitney_class): we have

$$w(\tilde{V}) = w(V) w(L_1) = w(\tilde{W}) = w(W) w(L_2)$$

where $L_1, L_2$ are the quotients, from which it follows that $w(L_1) = w(L_2)$, hence $L_1$ and $L_2$ are isomorphic. With no hypotheses on the codimension what we get is that the quotients have the same Stiefel-Whitney classes, which is weaker in general than being isomorphic, but is equivalent for line bundles.

Comment: In fact the additivity of $w_1$ with respect to direct sums implies that it suffices to assume that $\tilde{V}$ and $\tilde{W}$ (and for that matter, $V$ and $W$) have the same $w_1$, or equivalently isomorphic orientation bundles.